# Connection refused when trying to restart a thread for webscraper

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, webkit

I am using DryScrape to scrape a javascript page, and occasionally it kills the process if theres an error. I've tried using a catch according to the documentation to prevent it, but I haven't figured it out:

```
        try:
            sess.visit('url'))
        except webkit_server.EndOfStreamError:
            continue
        except webkit_server.NoResponeerror:
            continue
        except webkit_server.InvalidResponseError:
            continue
        except webkit_server.NoX11Error:
            continue
```

So I have a setup like this to restart threads if they crash:
class Checker():
    def check_if_thread_is_alive(self):
        a = ThreadClass()
        a.start()

```
    b = ThreadClass()
    b.start()

    c = ThreadClass()
    c.start()

    d = ThreadClass()
    d.start()

    while True:
        if not a.is_alive():
            print "Restarting A"
            a = ThreadClass()
            a.start()
        if not b.is_alive():
            print "Restarting B"
            b = ThreadClass()
            b.start()
        if not c.is_alive():
            print "Restarting C"
            c = ThreadClass()
            c.start()
        if not d.is_alive():
            print "Restarting D"
            d = ThreadClass()
            d.start()
```

However, I end up getting an error whenever I try to restart a thread:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Scrapper.py", line 30, in run
    sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'url')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dryscrape/session.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.driver = driver or DefaultDriver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dryscrape/driver/webkit.py", line 30, in __init__
    super(Driver, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 225, in __init__
    self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 444, in __init__
    self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 414, in connect
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", self._port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is there a better way of attempting to solve this problem, or something im missing?

Answer (score 4):

Cos :you're trying  connect to yourself.

```
need change target url.
```

if want connect to yourself, create service first.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 414, in connect
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", self._port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth <<<--- you're trying to connect to yourself.
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the exception, you can always use a catch-all exception handler like this. This is generally considered very bad pratice, but it DOES keep your scraper running if the error only happens occasionally:

```
try:
    sess.visit(url)
except Exception as e:
    # Print the exception for debugging here
    continue
```

And are you starting a local server for testing? From the traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 414, in connect
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", self._port))
```

You are actually connecting to localhost. If you start your own server, check the server log to see why it stops responding to connection requests.

---

Just spotted another mistake in your script:

```
sess.visit('url')
# it should be something like:
url = "http://www.google.com/"
sess.visit(url)
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet 'url' *was* a URL string, but it was changed for privacy reasons. Obviously a bad substitution which clearly causes confusion.